# How to resolve the Mysql connection issue in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new with Mysql and I have installed Mysql Workbench to practice queries. The issue I am facing is that after installation I have imported sql file and then try to connect to database. Could anyone please help me in guiding to connect and setup a database connection. I have read installation articles online but still the issue is not resolved.

I have added screenshots below so that I can show you what I am getting.

in first pic it says database and ssl connection error. This happens when I try to connect to database after importing sql file.
[image: error message]

[image: In second pic, it says the connection server is stopped]

Comment: did you install MySql Server? If yes, make sure it is running when you try to connect. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html

Comment: you should check the mysql error log to see if there is any problem.